# ¿como usar JSON en Google chart?

Tags: javascript, json, google-chart-api

estoy usando una tabla bootstrap de la cual genero Json con

```
$('#table').bootstrapTable('getData')
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y para pasar a google chart

```
var data = new google.visualization.dataTable($('#table').bootstrapTable('getData'));
```

pero da este error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Así no funciona?  `var jsonData=$('#table').bootstrapTable('getData');` y luego: `var data=google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(jsonData);`  o si no: `var data=google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(JSON.parse(jsonData));`

Comment: no funciono y el json.parse() da error de sintaxis

Comment: ¿Seguro que estás recibiendo un JSON válido? ¿Si copias y pegas el JSON en un [validador](https://jsonlint.com), pasa la validación?

Comment: da error porque es asi: Nombre: "Auditor1" y debe ser asi "Nombre": "Auditor1" sabes como solucionarlo

Comment: Tienes que verificar el origen de los datos, o sea, lo que obtienes aquí: `$('#table').bootstrapTable('getData')` No sé de dónde lo obtienes, por lo que no te puedo decir cómo solucionarlo. Lo que tienes que validar sería un `console.log`, o sea, el resultado de esto: `var jsonData=$('#table').bootstrapTable('getData');  console.log(jsonData);`

Comment: [{"Id":6,"Nombre":"Jonathan","Area":"IT","Focus":"1","DateAudit":"4/10/2018","Status":"Wait"},{"Id":18,"Nombre":"Jonathan","Area":"IT","Focus":"1","DateAudit":"4/11/2018","Status":"Wait"},{"Id":3,"Nombre":"Auditor1","Area":"IT","Focus":"1","DateAudit":"4/7/2018","Status":"En Espera"},{"Id":4,"Nombre":"Auditor1","Area":"IT","Focus":"1","DateAudit":"4/9/2018","Status":"En Espera"},{"Id":5,"Nombre":"Auditor1","Area":"IT","Focus":"1","DateAudit":"4/10/2018","Status":"En Espera"}]

Comment: probe con JSON.stringify($('#table').bootstrapTable('getData'))

Comment: Se puede apreciar que el JSON está dentro de un array, al estar entre `[]`, por tanto, debes acceder al índice `0`, para encontrar el objeto JSON. Crea la variable así: `var jsonData=$('#table').bootstrapTable('getData')[0];` y luego haz las diferentes pruebas. Como lo tenías originalmente: `var data = new google.visualization.dataTable(jsonData);`, y si no funciona, prueba de las otras formas que te sugerí en comentarios...

Comment: es un cadena no es un array

Comment: No no, si el `console.log` te imprime lo que pones en [este comentario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/156690/como-usar-json-en-google-chart?noredirect=1#comment294163_156690)  eso es un array, no una cadena. Los valores que vienen encerrados entre `[ ... ]` son array, no cadenas.

Answer (score -1):

Ese error lo puedes solucionar haciendo la carga del json en la función onload() o una que sea al cargar la página

Comment: favor de leer [answer]

Comment: Debes editar la respuesta y aportar un ejemplo practico completo de como hacerlo, para que sirva de respuesta para el actual usuario y futuros que puedan tener la misma duda. De momento esta respuesta se considera de mala calidad, motivo por el cual puede que recibas votos negativos.